# Regex get inconsistent length of string's value

Tags: javascript, regex

```
2f34435-something.jpg
4t44234-something.jpg
5465g67-something.jpg
```

says I have 3 string above, without using split, how can I do regex to get the value before dash? the length of strings is not consistent though..

Comment: Why don't you want to use split?

Comment: You don't need to use regex, **use string methods**. `str.substring(0, str.indexOf('-'));`

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to match one or more non-dash characters at the beginning of the string:

```
^[^-]+
```

- `^` - Anchor that denotes the beginning of the string
- `[^-]` - Character set to match all characters that are not dashes.
- `+` - One or more occurrences of non-dash characters.

For instance:

```
'2f34435-something.jpg'.match(/^[^-]+/);
// ["2f34435"]
```

With the `.split()` method, you would just need to retrieve the first match:

```
'2f34435-something.jpg'.split('-')[0];
// "2f34435"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use...

```
/^(.+?)-/gm
```

which will capture all 3 ( or as many as you have )

You can see it in action here  https://regex101.com/r/gD5sU2/2

This will also handle if you get - in the rest of the filename...

such as :-

```
2f34435-something-else.jpg
4t44234-something.jpg
5465g67-something.jpg
```

Comment: what does the plus sign do here? and do we need bracket?

Comment: . is any character and + is 1 or more

Comment: the brackets indicate the part you want to capture

Comment: I found the `^` is not required.

Comment: oh, it isn't in the examples, it was supposed to handle if there was another - in the filename, but that doesn't quite work.... I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

`([a-z0-9]+)-[a-z0-9]+.jpg` matches each of those strings and the string returned from the first group will match the text before the dash.

Comment: This will break if there's a second dash.

Answer (score 0):

Use look ahead for to do it

```
/^.+?(?=-)/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/mW5bO7/2